# Highcharts - Get y-axis data for a selected period of time

Tags: highcharts

I have this fiddle which enables you to get the selected period of time using the afterSetExtremes() event.

My problem is figuring out how to get a sum of the y-axis data for selected period.

I see that in the event object via target > series > data you can get the currently selected points and then loop through them getting a sum of the total, however it seems a bit of an unwieldy method and I was wondering if there was a quick simple API function which would give you this data a little more cleanly?

Edit - found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176459/highstock-how-programmatically-sum-selected-values-and-show-the-sum-to-user) of how to do this by the original author so presume there is no other way.

Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/L3rych99/1/

```
xAxis:{
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes:function(event){
            var start_date = new Date(event.min);
            var end_date = new Date(event.max);
            //console.log(event)
            //console.log(start_date + ' ' + end_date);
            //how to get sum of y-axis data between start and end data?           
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Answer by Sebastian is still actual - you need to calculate sum on your own. Highcharts doesn't provide method to get sum of actual points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i have found that when the data is larger than some threshold the data array is empty (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510307/highstocks-chart-series0-data-is-empty-in-aftersetextremes) - do you have a suggestion to handle summing y axis data in this scenario?